# Get caller IP Address

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ip-address

I have created an API using ASP.NET Web API. Normally all of my API caller make a portal which invoke my API. Is it possible if I want to get the IP of the caller, and not the portal?

Currently I'm using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`

But I believe this will return the IP of the portal. What I expecting is the IP of the person whois trigger the portal. Is it possible?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here, why do you think you need the IP address? Are you trying to **uniquely identify** users? If so, you can opt for `SessionID` or `Cookie`.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` is usually the IP address of the proxy server or router.